# Implementation of genomic recombination on lists of SNVs in Python

Tags: python, optimization, simulation, mutation, genetics

I'm coding a simulation of a population. Individuals have a genome with two chromosomes. The chromosomes are represented as lists of single nucleotide variations or mutations, I'm using numpy arrays with floats to represent the mutations but for clarity the examples will be shown as lists of integers. Note that the SNVs lists are ordered.

How recombination works basically is, with the examples of integers: I have two lists of integers for example `[0, 3, 6, 9]` and `[1, 2, 5, 11]` and then I have crossover points which represents where the recombination should happen, for example `[4, 10]`. The first recombination event (4) would have as a result `[0, 3, 5, 11]` and the second `[1, 2, 6, 9]`. The second recombination event (10), will result in `[0, 3, 5]` and the second `[1, 2, 6, 9, 11]`

I have already implemented this with the following code:

```
def recombine(snvs_0, snvs_1, crossovers):
    for crossover_point in crossovers:
        crossover_index_0 = bisect.bisect_left(snvs_0, crossover_point)
        crossover_index_1 = bisect.bisect_left(snvs_1, crossover_point)
        new_snvs_0 = snvs_0[:crossover_index_0] + snvs_1[crossover_index_1:]
        new_snvs_1 = snvs_1[:crossover_index_1] + snvs_0[crossover_index_0:]
        snvs_0 = new_snvs_0
        snvs_1 = new_snvs_1
    return snvs_0, snvs_1
```

The problem is, in the latests generations, the performance of this function is worse and worse because the number of mutations in the lists increases, which is expected. But this is a huge bottleneck for the performance of the whole program and slows thing a lot.

I wanted to know if there is another way that may be faster, I've tried other things but this seems to be the fastest way but I don't have a lot of experience with python and maybe there is a library or something more efficient to find where the crossovers should go.

Edit:

I have changed it so I don't copy each list every time:

```
def recombine(snvs_0, snvs_1, crossovers):
    for crossover_point in crossovers:
        crossover_index_0 = bisect.bisect_left(snvs_0, crossover_point)
        crossover_index_1 = bisect.bisect_left(snvs_1, crossover_point)
        snvs_0[crossover_index_0:], snvs_1[crossover_index_1:] = snvs_1[crossover_index_1:], snvs_0[crossover_index_0:]
    return snvs_0, snvs_1
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your current code is that it is using the bisect module to find the index of the crossover point in each list. This is a slow operation compare to numpy module of python. numpy module to find the index of the crossover point in each list. The numpy module has a function called searchsorted that can do this very efficiently. Another way if you want to keep the recombine function as it is, you can avoid creating new lists for each recombination event. Instead, you can modify the existing lists in-place by swapping the portions of the chromosomes beyond the crossover points.

Comment: I have change the code to not create the new lists, I've edited the post, and now it's faster (I didn't know I could do that so thanks!). I also tried using searchsorted before and just by swapping bisect_left with searchsorted and it takes quite longer, maybe I should use it in another way?